# How to exclude integers from all find command results

Tags: linux, integer, find

I feel like I'm so close to the answer looking through the forums here...  I'm successfully using the following command:

```
sudo find . -mindepth 1 -maxdepth 4 -type d -print0 >structure.txt
```

to get a text file of our file structure. The issue is that I need to `prune` out any file directories that have integers. We have THOUSANDS of sub-directories that our app creates that are numbered. Example:

```
Blue\clientfiles
Blue\clientfiles\saturn
Blue\clientfiles\saturn\moon
Blue\clientfiles\saturn\moon\33
Blue\clientfiles\saturn\moon\34
Blue\clientfiles\saturn\moon\35
Blue\documents
Blue\documents\1001
Blue\documents\1002
Blue\documents\1003
Blue\ftp
Blue\ftp\consumed
Blue\ftp\consumed\202
Blue\ftp\consumed\203
Blue\ftp\consumed\204
Blue\system
Blue\system\007
Blue\system\008
```

As you can see, part of the problem is that the depth varies... not just in the "Blue" directory, but the Red might have different depths as well. The only constant is that I do not need ANY of the numbered directories.  I can't figure out the proper `prune` syntax to exclude the numbered dirs.

Any insight would be appreciated!! ~R

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is rather unix.stackexchange question. Try to exclude all directories with digit on it's end:

```
egrep -v "[0-9]$"
```

(not compatible with print0)

Comment: Thanks Tomas. You're right~ I should've posted this in the unix area... whoops.
I'm not as familiar with egrep... i'll read up on it.  Do you know if it has an equivalent to -print0  (I'm stuck using it because some of the directories do have spaces... brilliant, i know :\ )

Comment: @RGuth, you usually need `-print0` to handle newlines, not spaces... FWIW, in GNU grep, you can use `-z`/`--null-data` to treat input as a set of null-byte-terminated lines.

Comment: @randomir hey~ thanks for response. I didn't realize that. Reading another post elsewhere lead me to believe it was related to the spaces and how xargs could, in turn, handle creating the directory structure from that file. Upon some testing, it does seem that the -print0 and -0 in xargs together are able to handle spaces and create directories called "Hold Score" (when not using the -print0 command, I was getting strange dangling directories called "Hold" and "Score")

Comment: @randomir also... I'm still super green in the linux/mac world. I'm assuming "treat input as a set of null-byte-terminated-lines" will break the output to separete lines per dir. I shall look into it :)

Comment: @RGuth, you can use `find -print0`/`xargs -0`/`grep -z`/`sed -z`/`sort -z`/etc to process filenames containing any character except `\0`. All these (UNIX) tools operate by default on lines - one record per line. If your filenames don't contain newlines (`\n`), it's perfectly safe to use them in the default mode (one entry/filename/path per line). If you can't guarantee  that, better use `-0`/`-z` option. Spaces, OTOH, are always safe to use. Just be sure to properly quote the variables holding them.

Comment: AFAIK, my filenames (well, directory names in my scenario) do not contain new lines... but they do contain spaces.

Comment: Ultimately, I used the following simplified command:
`find . -type d | egrep -v "[0-9]" >structure.txt`
This yielded what I needed... but using the xargs against that file still gives me "dangling" folders when presented with a name like "Hold Score".
Since my deadline is coming up at lunch (and truthfully, there are only about 100 directories with the annoying spaces) I went ahead and did a manual find~replace (find <space> and replace with \<space>) in Sublime Text to ensure the names were handled.  
Thanks again y'all.  This has been helpful!